# Detect The Users Taps

Tags: objective-c, uitapgesturerecognizer

I want to use tap gesture recognizer for detecting the user taps .i don't have much knowledge about this .Can anyone please help me for this .Tap Gesture .

I want to set the maximum count and i want to detect the user taps count if it is equal i want to perform some operation .Please help me to do this .

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[self.imageforcapture addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

The above code is simple example of tea gesture recognizer .

Thanks in advance !!!!

Comment: What is the problem in above code? Just set the number of taps as your require in your second line.

Comment: Here you can't set maximum and minimum count for tap.You can only set numerOfTouchesrequired to your required count.

Answer (score 1):

**Init Method :**

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[self.imageforcapture addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

**Handle Method :**

```
- (void)handleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender {
    i=i+1;
    if(i==10)
    {
        //Prforme task here
    }
}
```

Declare `i` as global variable

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(foundTap:)];
    tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    tapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];

-(void)foundTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{

    // Your code goes here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

self.imageforcapture.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[self.imageforcapture addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

First, you need to allow imageView to receive touches by adding line above.

Define global variable i.

```
@property NSInteger i;
```

in viewDidLoad set the value of i to 0

```
self.i = 0;
```

After that you need to handle that global i variable that will track taps.

```
- (void)handleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender {
self.i++;
if (self.i == 10) {
//Perform your expected behaviour
}
}
```